# Set a variable to 2 but console.log says it's undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To give a brief overview I am creating a loading bar that needs to go from 0 - 100 based on the total num of pins dropped onto a map in comparison to how many possible locations there are. So bellow I have some logic as to how I am going about achieving that.

```
//pin drop counter
var pDrop = 2;
//secondary drop counter
var dropCounter = pDrop
//result length counter
var rLength;

//pin drops and then runs the check marker count function
function dropPin(){ checkMarkerCount() }

//if a new pin was dropped then we increase the size of the bar 
function checkMarkerCount() {
  if (dropCounter != pDrop) {
    moveBar();
  }

 function moveBar() {
   //selects the loading bar from the DOM
   var barEl = document.getElementById("pro-bar");   
   //states how wide the bar is
   var barW = 1; 
   //dictates how fast it moves
   var barid = setInterval(frame, 10);
   //gets how many pins have dropped
   var counter = pDrop; 

  function frame(counter) {
    //rLength is the length of an array = the total amount of possible pin drops
    if (counter >= rLength) {
      clearInterval(barid);
    } else {
      barW = counter; 
      barEl.style.width = barW + '%'; 
      console.log(barW)
    }
  }
}
}
```

The issues is that even if I say that pDrop is equal to 2 it will log that the length is undefined.... What have I done wrong?

Comment: "will log that the length is undefined" - you are talking about `rLength`?

Comment: `var barid = setInterval(frame, 10);` frame should take 1 arg (counter). you console log barW, and before that you put barW = counter. but what is counter?

Comment: Sidenote: there's a loadingbar html element in html5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the concept of variables and arguments.

```
function frame(i_counter) {
    //rLength is the length of an array = the total amount of possible pin drops
    if (i_counter >= rLength) {
      clearInterval(barid);
    } else {
      barW = i_counter; 
      barEl.style.width = barW + '%'; 
      console.log(barW)
    }
  }
```

When you call the `function frame`, you should set params `i_counter`.
You think `counter` you passed as argument is the same you set above.
And `barW = counter` on your code take the argument you set.

I changed your code a bit, so you don't get rid of `counter` argument.
When executing frame, do this:

```
setInterval(function () {
   frame(2);
}, 10);
```

Comment: `$` to most people indicates that the variable represents a jquery object. `i` for increment is more common for this situation.